# Handle PopUp in selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, popup

I am new to selenium. I am having a pop up. i have attached the picture. How can I handle it. I have tried `switch_to_alert()`

but it did not worked.

[image]

Comment: It's not an alert. It's an HTML dialog. Treat it like any other HTML on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an alert, so it should be handled as common element:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[text()="Process Payments"]'))).click()
```

to confirm

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[text()="Cancel"]'))).click()
```

to decline

Comment: If it doesn't work, share HTML-code for that popup as my XPath might not select required buttons

Comment: Can you please help me in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54347439/capture-screenshot-of-failed-test-cases/54347657?noredirect=1#comment95512505_54347657