# Capture screenshot of failed test cases

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, screenshot

How can I capture a screenshot of the failed test cases in Selenium + Python? I am able to get screenshots of the page but is facing difficulty in capturing screenshots of failed test cases.

Code:

```
def test_2new(self):

   driver = self.driver driver.get("google.com") 
   driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("Automation") 
   driver.set_page_load_timeout(10) 
   driver.find_element_by_name("btnK").click() 
   self.assertTrue("something.com" in self.driver.current_url) 
   print("Google Search") 

@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls): 

    # cls.driver.refresh() 
    time.sleep(5) 
    if sys.exc_info()[0]: 
         cls.driver.save_screenshot(r"C:\Users\ANCP2\sample.png")
```

Comment: Post your code trials.

Comment: @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):

        time.sleep(5)
        if sys.exc_info()[0]:
            cls.driver.save_screenshot(r"C:\Users\ANCP2\sample.png")

Comment: @Talib, try this: `def test_2new(self):
        driver = self.driver 
        try: 
            driver.get("google.com")
            driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("Automation") 
            driver.set_page_load_timeout(10) 
            driver.find_element_by_name("btnK").click() 
            self.assertTrue("something.com" in self.driver.current_url) 
            print("Google Search") 
        except:
            driver.get_screenshot_as_file("C:\Users\ANCP2\sample.png")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like:

```
def test_2new(self):

    driver = self.driver 
    driver.get("google.com")
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
    driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("Automation")  
    driver.find_element_by_name("btnK").click()

    try:

        self.assertTrue("something.com" in self.driver.current_url) 
        print("Google Search!")

    except AssertionError:

        driver.save_screenshot(r"C:\Users\ANCP2\sample.png")
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: def test_2new(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("http://www.google.com")
        driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("Automation")
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
        driver.find_element_by_name("btnK").click()
        self.assertTrue("something.com" in self.driver.current_url)
        print("Google Search")
    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        # cls.driver.refresh()
        time.sleep(5)
        if sys.exc_info()[0]:
            cls.driver.save_screenshot(r"C:\Users\ANCP2\sample.png")

Comment: I am using this code. I have used the assertion to fail that test case and when I run it it shows me the assertion error

Comment: @Talib, I have updated the answer. Check it, please.

Comment: Can I use it in my teardownclass function

Comment: @Talib, in your current realization -- no.

Comment: It's better to do after each assertion in your tests.

Comment: Suppose I am not using any assertion and my test case fails then how can I capture screenchot of that test case

Comment: @Talib, no sense in your test cases if you are not using assertions at all.

Comment: @Talibm you can do a screenshot at the end of each test case but in `tearDown` method not `tearDownClass`.

Comment: @Talib, do you have any other question? Your problem is solved, so you can accept my answer (check a tick near my answer). Thanks.